# Firebase Messaging Error(Android only) - Fatal Exception on new Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are currently using flutter to develop an app that receives push notifications. Everything worked fine until we did the last Flutter update and now we get a Fatal Exception inside Firebase - FlutterFirebaseMessagingService on Android only.

I couldn't find anything about this on the flutter git so it might be an android problem.

This happens the moment when the app gets a new Notification using Firebase functions and Firebase Messaging. Sample Data we use:

```
{
  notification: {
        title: „hello",
        body: „You got a new Message"
    },
    data: {
        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        additional: additional, // some integer values
        message: messageText // Same as message body above
    },
    apns: {
        payload: {
            aps: {
                badge: count,
            },
        },
    },
    token: deviceToken //this is a correct device id
}


admin.messaging().send(message)
```

Full Device Log

> E/AndroidRuntime( 3436): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Firebase-FlutterFirebaseMessagingService E/AndroidRuntime( 3436):
>   Process: de.mandarinmedien.jutta, PID: 3436 E/AndroidRuntime( 3436):
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   zzc(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzz; in class
>   Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzz; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.firebase.iid.zzz' appears in
>   /data/app/de.mandarinmedien.jutta-gn2RX8mWXXycpVEEEZIaNQ==/base.apk:classes3.dex)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3436):        at
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown
>   Source:110) E/AndroidRuntime( 3436):        at
>   com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:4) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3436):        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3436):        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3436):        at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown
>   Source:6) E/AndroidRuntime( 3436):        at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Does anyone already have experience with this error or has an idea how to solve it ?

Edit: android/app/build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ******
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.1"
            }
        }
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please add the `build.gradle`, because the stack-trace alone might not suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error message hints for `iid`; the instance ID service. this might be provided by `firebase-core`; while it could also be incompatible versions, which occassionaly lead to unknown methods and fields.

try to update:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

to the current versions:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

the `firebase-perf` plugin has to be at the top, not the bottom:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

also the library is outdated (possibly might require `firebase-core`):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2'
```

while I really wonder, why there is no dependency for `FCM` (as one would expect it):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
```

once targeting API level 28, it is also suggested to setup a notification channel:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

... the support libraries would be at version `28.0.0` currently.

remark: the invalid JSON syntax might (most likely) come from posting it wrongfully - otherwise other platforms would not function either; I've just added an explanation what is wrong with it and removed the hard-coded values. the stack-trace tells a whole other story, not hinting for any invalid syntax.

Comment: Im sorry that i cant upvote your answer but the import of firebase-messaging fixed it. 

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'

Now im not sure why it worked up to flutter 6.0.0 without this import but thank you

Comment: Could you explain why the order of the firebase-pref plugin is important, i didn't had any problems with it ?

Comment: @ManuelBachmann per default Gradle plugins should be applied before `android` configuration, in order to have them available then (it is sequential execution) - while the `com.google.gms.google-services` is rather an exception, which has to reside after the `android` configuration, because it adds values, which originate from the parsed `google-services.json`... basically, at first the plugin gets referenced, then the library which depends on the plugin is referenced; it might work at the bottom, too - while the documentation still recommends to place it on top.